Zero Shunt Resistance in Ammeter

To reduce the resistance of ammeter, we attach a shunt resistance in parallel to the galvanometer. Also, this allows galvanometer to measure larger currents even though it has less value of the full scale current allowed to pass through it.

In an ammeter, if my shunt's resistance is zero (theoretically speaking), will the galvanometer be able to detect any current i.e. show any deflection? What will happen if I pass infinite current through it?

If I understand your question, placing a shunt resistance of zero Ohms in your circuit would make the voltage drop across the ammeter zero (which I'm defining as the galvanometer + resistance of the galvanometer path).  Therefore, the ammeter would not show any deflection.

Yeah that's what I thought too. But theoretically speaking if we pass infinite current through the ammeter somehow, then will any current flow through the galvanometer in it?

$V=iR$ or $V/R=i.$  If $V=0$ (and $R > 0$ for the galvanometer path) then $i=0.$  Does that make sense?

It's hard to say what would happen is every charged particle in the universe were passing through the ammeter in the shortest imaginable time.  I suspect the ammeter could be damaged.

@ad2004 I agree but for infinite current, the potential difference through the shunt path will be given by Ir. Now, I is infinity anyways and r is 0. Then, V = ir = ∞. 0 which is undefined though it tends towards 1. Now what...

@M.Enns Definitely, but theoretically assuming that no heat dissipates in any way and no damage takes place what to think then...

Perhaps I should say that having a shunt resistance of zero is equivalent to a zero voltage drop:  This is the working assumption.  Therefore, even with an infinite current, the resulting voltage drop is zero.

okay thanks for your help

Think of an ammeter as a voltmeter measuring a voltage $V$ across the resistance of the ammeter $R$, ie $I = \dfrac VR$ and the deflection of the needle, $V$, is calibrated in amps.
Adding a shunt, $R_\rm s$ across the ammeter changes its effective resistance to $\dfrac{R\,R_{\rm s}}{R+R_{\rm s}}$.
Thus when there is a voltage $V$ across the terminals of the ammeter with the shunt the current is $I'= \dfrac VR\cdot \left (1+\dfrac{R}{R_{\rm s}} \right)$.
Thus the ammeter with the shunt needs a larger current to give the same voltage (deflection on the scale) with a multiplicative factor of $\left (1+\dfrac{R}{R_{\rm s}} \right)$.
Thus, making the shunt resistor smaller results in the ammeter being able to measure a larger current.
You will perhaps see the folly of making the resistance of the shunt zero as this leads to an infinite (meaningless) multiplicative factor.

Agreed, thanks!
